# how to change formatting percentage to number in excel with pywin32 at python3.6

Tags: python, formatting, percentage, pywin32

I want to change formatting `%` to number in excel with `pywin32` at `python3.6`

this is my code.

```
def qms(self):
    fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)

    if fname[0]:
        self.Filename.setText(fname[0])
        excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible = True
        f = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname[0])
        fs = f.ActiveSheet
        lastrow = fs.UsedRange.Rows.Count

        for i in range(lastrow, 2, -1):
            if fs.Cells(i,5).Value == None or fs.Cells(i,5).Value == "":
                fs.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete()
            elif fs.Cells(i,2).Value == "Wire sweep율":
                for x in range(11, 21):
                    fs.Cells(i,x).Value = fs.Cells(i,x).Value * 100
                    print(fs.Cells(i,x).Value)
```

if do that `4.24% -> 424%`. I want to `4.24% -> 4.24`.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
def qms(self):
        fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
        if fname[0]:
            self.Filename.setText(fname[0])
            excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
            excel.Visible = True
            f = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname[0])
            fs = f.ActiveSheet
            lastrow = fs.UsedRange.Rows.Count

            for i in range(lastrow, 2, -1):
                if fs.Cells(i,5).Value == None or fs.Cells(i,5).Value == "":
                    fs.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete()
                elif fs.Cells(i,2).Value == "Wire sweep율":
                    for x in range(11, 21):
                        fs.Cells(i,x).NumberFormat ="G/표준"
                        fs.Cells(i,x).Value = fs.Cells(i,x).Value * 100
```